# Where can I find supported Tesseract options

Tags: r

I've been frustrated because I see options reported in `tesseract_params()` but I can't set them.  How do I find what's available and what's not?  As an aside, is this package being actively maintained? Thanks.

```
library(tesseract)
tesseract_params("preserve_interword_spaces")
#>                         param default                               desc
#> 425 preserve_interword_spaces       0 Preserve multiple interword spaces

tesseract(options = list("preserve_interword_spaces"="1"))
#> <tesseract engine>
#>  loaded: eng 
#>  datapath: C:\Users\Apste\AppData\Local\tesseract5\tesseract5\tessdata/ 
#>  available: eng osd

tesseract_params("preserve_interword_spaces")
#>                         param default                               desc
#> 425 preserve_interword_spaces       0 Preserve multiple interword spaces
```

Created on 2022-11-22 with reprex v2.0.2

Comment: Looks like recent activity in the Issues of their repo, so I would assume it's being actively maintained: https://github.com/ropensci/tesseract/issues?q=is%3Aissue

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the options in the engine you pass to `ocr`, rather than using global options.

Let's use the following image for an example:

---

[image]

---

By default, there will be no space produced between "Hello" and "world":

```r
library(tesseract)

cat(ocr('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eylcC.png'))
#> This is a tesseract test. Here are words with a large space between them:
#> Hello world
```

To run tesseract with interword spacing preserved, we create an engine with that option set and pass it to `ocr`:

```
my_eng <- tesseract(options = list(preserve_interword_spaces = "1"))

cat(ocr('https://i.stack.imgur.com/eylcC.png', my_eng))
#> This is a tesseract test. Here are words with a large space between them:
#> Hello                                                   world
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>